# Comma in currency exchange API?

Tags: url-parameters

I am using https://wahrungsrechner.org/api/ to get the target currency amount for a source currency amount.

This works: [Link](https://api.wahrungsrechner.org/v1/quotes/USD/EUR/json?quantity=109&key=2274%7CJWUK%5EbUU*vL~z4pnT4oaJQUeQ*ZdPyL8)

This does not work due to the `,` at the quantity, it always uses 1 as quantity: [Link](https://api.wahrungsrechner.org/v1/quotes/USD/EUR/json?quantity=109,56&key=2274%7CJWUK%5EbUU*vL~z4pnT4oaJQUeQ*ZdPyL8)

I tried with `.` instead of `,` without success. Anyone any ideas what else I might try?

Thanks

Comment: The HTML encoded comma is `%2C`, but that didn't work for me either.  Are you sure that this API accepts decimal inputs?

Comment: Tried that in the meanwhile, too ... not sure about decimal inputs, but since its a currency calculator it should :-D.